# How to get authorization code in BigCommerce to generate access token once the app is already installed in a store

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, bigcommerce

I am providing an integration to BigCommerce from our website.

I see that the auth url is called with the authorization code when app is first installed. I need to know how I can generate the authorization code with an app already installed.

I need it because there's a case where the user removes the integration from our website but our app is still installed in his store in BigCommerce. I want to show something like a 'connect' button which the user can click to generate a new access token and connect his store to our website.

I understand that I can reuse the same access token that he had before he removed the integration, but then what if the user connects a second account in our website to his BigCommerce store. In this case the access token will need to be passed between two different accounts in our website and will be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

An app should only connect to a store actively, in a process that will install the app. If you're offering the ability to disable the integration outside of BigCommerce, the app should be uninstalled at the same time from the store. The same OAuth token is required to authorize any API requests for the app, which is why it needs to be stored after installation.